# How to use Database with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to make login in Node.js. but i am confused how to use database.And my Login.html & database.js is like. http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local So please give me proper idea.

```
<form action="/login" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Login</button>
```

database.js:

```
module.exports = {
    'url' : 'your-database-here' 

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `server.js` should be this bit of code (assuming you are following the tutorial you linked exactly).

```
var configDB = require('./config/database.js');
mongoose.connect(configDB.url);
```

According to that code, your `database.js` file must be in a **config** folder (rather then in the same folder as `server.js`). So make sure you are doing that.

Next, place your mongodb url like so in your `database.js`.

```
module.exports = {
    'url' : 'mongodb://<user>:<pass>@mongo.onmodulus.net:27017/Mikha4ot'
};
```

Make sure to replace `<user>` with your username and `<pass>` with your password.

### Need help getting a mongoDB database for yourself?

I will help you.

### 1:

[**Go to Mongolab's signup page**](https://mongolab.com/signup/).

### 2:

Once signed up, tap the [image] button.

### 3:

Choose the **Cloud provider** you want. *(I just kept Amazon since it was already selected)*

### 4:

When you get to the **Plan** section, make sure you choose the free plan (unless of course you want to pay).

[image]

### 5:

Once you create the database, click into it!

[image]

### 6:

Now you will find the **connection url** that you want to put in your `module.exports`

[image]

Comment: If i used mySql Database then how i can used?

Comment: Try submitting a new question about that. Something like "How do I connect to a mySQL database with Node.js?". You should try searching on Google first, of course. Try including `site:stackoverflow.com` or `site:github.com` with some keywords for better results.

Answer (score 1):

It depends which database you are using. Different databases often have different ways of accessing them. For example, if you are using postgres you can use [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) from npm.

Answer (score 0):

From the tutorial you link to:

> Fill this in with your own database. If you don’t have a MongoDB database lying around, I would suggest going to [Modulus.io](https://modulus.io/) and grabbing one. Once you sign up (and you get a $15 credit for signing up), you can create your database, grab its **connection url**, and place it in this file.

Otherwise you will need to download [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) and run your own instance of it.

Alternatively, rewrite the database code to use a different kind of database and find [an NPM module to interface with it](https://www.npmjs.org/).